# White lines in matplotlib's pcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib

In some pdf viewers such as Preview on OSX, plots made with `matplotlib`'s pcolor have white lines (see image below). How can I get rid of them?

The source code is very simple (choose any data for `x`,`y`,`z`):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("pdf")
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
pl.figure()
pl.pcolormesh(x,y,z,cmap="Blues",linewidth=0) 
pl.savefig("heatmap.pdf")
```

[image]

Comment: This is because `pcolormesh` actually draws individual rectangles, and some pdf viewers render them differently than others.  Both as a workaround and because it's more efficient, it's better to use `imshow` in this case.  For example, in your case: `plt.imshow(z, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Blues', extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])`.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was locking for.

Comment: A similar issue exists for the color bar. Do you have an idea for a workaround for that?

Comment: You can work around that by passing in `rasterized=True` to `colorbar`.

Comment: I'm getting an "unexpected keyword argument 'rasterized'" error when calling `pl.colorbar(rasterized=True)`. With MPL version 1.3.1 and 1.4.x. The top answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003353/why-does-my-colorbar-have-lines-in-it) works for me.

Comment: Try `cb.solids.set_rasterized(True)`

Comment: This is a long-ongoing bug in Matplotlib, and for 10 years there seems to be no solution still. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1188

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The comments have a good solution that utilizes `imshow`. When `imshow` is not appropriate for the input data (e.g. it is not uniformly spaced) this generally solves this problem,

```
pcol = pl.pcolormesh(x,y,z,cmap="Blues",linewidth=0,)
pcol.set_edgecolor('face')
```

If that approach does not reduce the lines sufficiently, you can also try this:

```
pl.pcolormesh(x,y,z,cmap="Blues",linewidth=0,rasterized=True)
```

In addition to reducing the lines between squares this approach also tends to reduce file size a bit, which is sometimes useful.  In this case you may want to tune the `dpi` setting when saving (e.g. `pl.savefig("heatmap.pdf", dpi=300)`) until you get something that is satisfactory.

Comment: For `evince` just the `set_edgecolor` was enough (note that for a colorbar it is `cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("face")`).

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem, using `rasterized=True` solved it (on matplotlib version `3.1.0`).

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer didn't work very well for me. I seemed to have gotten closer by using `antialiased=True`, in addition to `linewidth=0`. This was with matplotlib version `3.0.2`. Note the middle plot corresponds to the best version.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(15,5))
axes[0].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, norm=norm, cmap='magma', alpha=0.5, antialiased=True)
axes[1].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, norm=norm, cmap='magma', alpha=0.5, antialiased=True, linewidth=0.0)
axes[2].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, norm=norm, cmap='magma', alpha=0.5, antialiased=False, linewidth=0.0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer by @eqzx:
If you set alpha=1, you will get better results as far as grid lines are concerned. However, your application/use case may differ.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

zz = xx**2 + yy*2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(15,5))
axes[0,0].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, cmap='magma', alpha=0.5, antialiased=True)
axes[0,1].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, cmap='magma', alpha=0.5, antialiased=True, linewidth=0.0)
axes[0,2].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, cmap='magma', alpha=0.5, antialiased=False, linewidth=0.0)
axes[1,0].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, cmap='magma', alpha=1, antialiased=True)
axes[1,1].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, cmap='magma', alpha=1, antialiased=True, linewidth=0.0)
axes[1,2].pcolormesh(XX, YY, ZZ_r, zorder=-1, cmap='magma', alpha=1, antialiased=False, linewidth=0.0)
```

[See plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nln4m.jpg)