# In Python, how can I inherit and override a method on a class instance, assigning this new version to the same name as the old one?

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, plot, instance

In Matplotlib, a common problem are unwanted white lines between `Patch` objects drawn with `pcolor`, `pcolormesh`, and `contourf` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092991/white-lines-in-matplotlibs-pcolor) for the former two and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263769/hide-contour-linestroke-on-pyplot-contourf-to-get-only-fills) for the latter).

I've attempted to fix this automatically by adding new methods to my `Axes`  class/subclass instances using `MethodType`. I do this instead of subclassing simply because I want to generate `Axes` by passing slices of `GridSpec` objects to the `add_subplot` method on a `Figure` instance, and I am not aware of how I could do this with some kind of subclassed `matplotlib.axes.Subplot` (but I welcome advice). Here is some example code:

```py
from types import MethodType
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

f = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2,1)
ax = f.add_subplot(gs[0,0])

def _pcolormesh(self, *args, **kwargs):
    p = self.pcolormesh(*args, **kwargs)
    p.set_edgecolor('face')
    p.set_linewidth(0.2) # Will cover white lines, without making dot in corner of each square visible
    return p

def _contourf(self, *args, **kwargs):
    c = self.contourf(*args, **kwargs)
    for _ in c.collections:
        _.set_edgecolor('face')
    return c

ax.mypcolormesh = MethodType(_pcolormesh, ax)
ax.mycontourf = MethodType(_contourf, ax)
```

In the last line, I would prefer to be able to write `ax.pcolormesh` **instead of** `ax.mypcolormesh`, but this raises a `RecursionError`, because `_pcolormesh` calls the original method name... which is now aliased to itself.

So, how can I access a method on this `Axes` instance, override it, and preserve the original name?

Comment: So the fix to the original problem is 2 lines, and to make this fix "easier" you add 6 lines?! Does not seem to make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I just don't like copying and pasting two lines a million times. I have to make *a lot* of plots. These 6 lines go into a function that automatically builds a structure of subplots, so it's really me adding 6 lines to avoid typing 2 lines 1000 times for the rest of my graduate program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The efficient solution

Since replacing the method for each axis individually is a lot more typing than using a simple function, the most efficient method would be to create a Python file, `myhacks.py`, with the respective function

```
def pcolormesh(ax, *args, **kwargs):
    p = ax.pcolormesh(*args, **kwargs)
    p.set_edgecolor('face')
    p.set_linewidth(0.2)
    return p
```

And use it whenever the improved version of the pcolormesh is needed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import myhacks as m
# ...other imports

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m.pcolormesh(ax, other_arguments)
```

This works also well for already created files, where one would simply search an replace `"ax.pcolormesh("` with `"m.pcolormesh(ax,"` (if necessary using regex for possible other axes names).

#### The academic solution

It is of course possible to subclass `matplotlib.axes.Axes` to include the desired function. Since there is no real benefit of this, except knowing how to do it, I would call it "academic solution".

So, again we can create a file, `myhacks.py`, for our custom class, register the custom class as a projection to Matplotlib,

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection

class MyAxes(Axes):
    name = 'mycoolnewaxes'
    def pcolormesh(self,*args, **kwargs):
        p = Axes.pcolormesh(self,*args, **kwargs)
        p.set_edgecolor('face')
        p.set_linewidth(0.2)
        return p

register_projection(MyAxes)
```

And use this by importing it and creating the axes using the projection:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import myhacks as m

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2,1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0], projection='mycoolnewaxes')

z = np.random.rand(10,13)
ax.pcolormesh(z)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... I solved it, sort of. Just use

```py
ax._contourf = ax.contourf
```

which saves a copy of the old method, and then, for example,

```py
def _contourf(self, *args, **kwargs):
    c = self._contourf(*args, **kwargs)
    for collection in c.collections:
        collection.set_edgecolor('face')
    return c
ax.contourf = MethodType(_contourf, ax)
```

which assigns the new method to call the copy of the old method.

Comment: A clear explanation of this kind of approach is given [here](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2013/07/05/run-time-method-patching-python/).

Comment: @LukeDavis Why iterate with the variable `_`? `collection` or `artist` would be more descriptive.