# Is there a way to avoid gridding artifact with plt.colormesh when alpha is turned down

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm using `plt.colormesh` overtop of an image. When I turn down the alpha of `plt.colormesh` so that the image shows through, plt.colormesh creates a griding effect due to the overlap in the edges. To be accurate there is no overlap in the points, but the density of the points and large scale causes the points to share space.

Example:
**`plt.colormesh` alpha 1.0**

[image: Full opacity]

**`plt.colormesh` alpha 0.5**

[image: Gridding]

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/27096694/4435344 suggestions: 300 dpi, no edges,  face color, no linewidth**

[image: highres]

**Previous plot plus `antialiased=True`**
[image: antialiased]

Comment: The main option that I'm considering is to swap the order of the layers. By putting the map ontop and turning the alpha down of the google maps instead of the data. The only downside of this is that the map of northern Canada would show up faintly without data behind it.

Comment: Also considering moving this to the geospatial data stack, but I feel this may be appropriate here.

Comment: This might be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092991/white-lines-in-matplotlibs-pcolor

Comment: @DavidG I just tried the suggested changes from that thread, as well as increasing the figure size, and it was unable to fix the issue.

Comment: @DavidG I'll try the second answer. This does seem like a duplicate thread at the moment.

Comment: @DavidG Yes adding `antialiased=True` essentially solved the problem to where it is not as noticable. Link or close the question?

Comment: I add `rasterized=True` to avoid this problem when I save the plot as a pdf file

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I'm tempted to find the minimal solution that fixes this. I ultimately added a half dozen lines. I added `rasterized=True, linewidth=0, antialiased=True` to `plt.colormesh`. `binned_plot.set_edgecolor('face')` after the call and `figsize=figsize, dpi=figdpi` to the `savefig` command.