# Pixels shown when saving colormap as vector graphics

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, vector-graphics

I'm plotting (using `pcolormesh`) some colourmap figures to be added to my report written in Latex. I hope to save the figure as `pdf` so that I could use vector graphics in my report and Latex is happy to read `pdf`.

However, the saved figure shows white lines (which I assume are tiny gaps) separating the pixels. When I save it as `png`, it looks fine. I'm wondering if it's possible to make the `pdf` looks like the `png` one.

[image: pdf]

[image: png]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [White lines in matplotlib's pcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092991/white-lines-in-matplotlibs-pcolor)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with exporting slabs or strips of gradient colours as they are boundaried areas. Here is Acrobat plug-in within MS Edge (no way to control visually)
[image]

The viewers in some cases can compensate for the vector display by means of blending the edges. Here the difference in the viewer is achieved by simply pressing A for "Anti-Alias", but several setting may or may not be present depending on viewer.

[image]

From https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-there-unwanted-borders

> Acrobat Reader (cross platform)
> There are options in Preferences to enable/disable text smoothing, image smoothing and line art smoothing. Disable line art smoothing.

> Preview (macOS)
> There is an option in Preferences to enable/disable anti-aliasing of text and line art. Disable this option.

> GSview (cross platform)
> There are settings for Text Alpha and Graphics Alpha. Change Graphics Alpha from 4 bits to 1 bit to disable graphic anti-aliasing.

> gv (Unix-like X)
> There is an option to enable/disable anti-aliasing. Disable this option.

> Evince (Linux/GNOME)
> There is not an option to disable anti-aliasing in this viewer.

> Okular (Linux/KDE)
> There is not an option in the GUI to enable/disable anti-aliasing. From a console command line, use:
> $ kwriteconfig --file okularpartrc --group 'Dlg Performance' 
> --key GraphicsAntialias Disabled
> Then restart Okular. Change the final word to ‘Enabled’ to restore the original setting.

And I can confirm there is **NO configuration setting in SumatraPDF** even though based on MuPDF
[image]

Even if a viewer compensates for those blocks, it may still have problems with other boundaries where stroking is "none", see top right of this zoomed in section. if a line is present in a PDF it is expected to be displayed at given width, but you cannot say a pdf pixel is zero dimension.

[image]

### Workaround

Importing a bitmap (which will on import to PDF be **converted from PNG**) is one way to fix pixel dimensions at a scale.