# Black lines when saving 3D surface to pdf: How can I get rid of them?

Tags: matplotlib, export, surface

I have the following code to display a 3D surface using `ax.plot_surface`:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X,Y = np.meshgrid(range(k_mean.shape[0]), range(k_mean.shape[1])) 
Z   = k_mean
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0., alpha=0.8, cmap=cm.nipy_spectral, antialiased=False, shade=False)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=0, cmap=cm.nipy_spectral)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=0, cmap=cm.nipy_spectral)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=120, cmap=cm.nipy_spectral)

ax.set_xlim(0, 120)
ax.set_ylim(0, 120)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('3d.pdf', dpi=500)
```

The display of the plot in Spyder is "correct", but the PDF seems to ignore the `linewidth=0.`. How can I fix that?

Spyder output:
[image: Spyder output]

PDF output:
[image: PDF output]

Comment: this cropped up before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766481/matplotlib-plot-surface-hidden-lines-appearing-in-pdf but not clear it was fixed

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! I didn't find that one!

Answer (score 3):

matplotlib github think this is fixed but that the fix didn't make it into v1.4.1 but will be put in v1.4.3
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2247

Comment: Thank you! I updated my matplotlib now to the latest version 1.4.3 and everything works fine!

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, this is related to a bug in the pdf backend, which should be resolved in the newest version of matplotlib.

This is hack / workaround to get slightly more appealing results also in older versions. You can set the edgecolor explicitly to fully transparent:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=True, edgecolor=(0,0,0,0))
```

Results for comparison:
[image] [image]

#### EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, using the `alpha` keyword overwrites the alpha value of the edge color. Thus, we need to define transparency for the face colors explicitly. The simplest way I can see, is to adapt the colormap:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = np.array(cm.coolwarm(np.linspace(0,1,256)))
colors[:,3] = 0.6
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('alpha_cmap', colors.tolist())

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cmap,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=True, edgecolor=(0,0,0,0))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: In case anyone tries this (which seems to work): as well as setting edgecolor, this fix needs to exclude the alpha keyword argument - even apha=1.0 seems to stop it working.

Comment: Good point. The `alpha` keyword overwrites color specific alpha values in (almost?) all matplotlib functions.

Comment: @paddyg I added an example of how to add transparency to the face colors.